# Trying to Define `$` Type

Tags: sml, ml

Using Standard ML of New Jersey (v110.77), I'm trying to define the `$` data type from Purely Functional Data Structures:

```ml
datatype alpha susp = $ of alpha
```

But I get an error:

```
- datatype alpha susp = $ of alpha;
stdIn:1.11-2.7 Error: syntax error: deleting  ID ID EQUALOP
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Standard ML, type variables are prefixed with a single quote:

```ml
datatype 'alpha susp = $ of 'alpha
```

Comment: +1. Note that it's actually conventional to write `'a` rather than `'alpha` (though we do *pronounce* it "alpha").