# "operator is not a function" on `$` Usage

Tags: sml

Given the following:

```
// credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802305/trying-to-define-type
datatype 'alpha susp = $ of 'alpha 

fun sum n = if n = 0 then 1
            else n + sum(n-1)
```

What does this error mean?

```
- use "Lazy.sml";
[opening Lazy.sml]
datatype 'a susp = $ of 'a
val sum = fn : int -> int
val it = () : unit
- val foo = $sum 100000000000;
stdIn:17.5-17.28 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: (int -> int) susp
  in expression:
    ($ sum) 100000000000
```

Comment: in my sml repl, it works.

Comment: Can you post your version please?

Comment: Standard ML of New Jersey v110.77 [built: Sat Aug 23 16:12:36 2014]

Answer (score 1):

after you declare a new datatype, you should use it as a function(actually it is indeed turned into a function):

```
- datatype 'alpha susp = $ of 'alpha;
datatype 'a susp = $ of 'a
- fun sum n = if n = 0 then 1
=             else n + sum(n-1);
val sum = fn : int -> int
- $(sum 10);
val it = $ 56 : int susp
- $;
val it = fn : 'a -> 'a susp
```

## update

in your question, you have error:

```
- val foo = $sum 100000000000;
stdIn:17.5-17.28 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: (int -> int) susp
  in expression:
    ($ sum) 100000000000
```

notice that:

```
[tycon mismatch]
```

and

```
operator: (int -> int) susp
  in expression:
    ($ sum) 100000000000
```

it means it's a type error, the type mismatched. you should know function in sml takes only one parameter, so it's very easy to find out the association:

the expression `$ sum 100000000000` is equivalent to `(($ sum) 100000000000)`, which means you create a variable `($ sum)` first, which has a type of `(int -> int) susp`, and then use it as a function and pass parameters to it, which cause this error.

actually the way you call this functions as a chain has a name in sml(or even in general functional programming), called `curry`. you can have a look at corresponding documentation.

Comment: So `$ (sum 100000)` won't work either since, I believe that I've observed, `sml` uses eager evaluation: The result of this call was - `uncaught exception Overflow [overflow]`

Comment: @KevinMeredith unfortunately not so easy. sml is eager eval in nature. but there are common techniques that can be applied to make any eager eval progfun lazy: `streaming`. and every eval of streaming api returns two values: the desired value itself, and a lambda, which has no param to eval the next pair, which is called `thunk`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith if you are worrying about overflow, it's a language implementation limit, you need to find another way around.http://sml-family.org/Basis/int-inf.html#IntInf:STR:SPEC